# What is this kind of variable definition called in Matlab (A.b =1 and A.f =4 ...)?

Tags: arrays, matlab, variables, matrix, declaration

I have come through this kind of declaration which, for me, looks like an array of variables which have a parent variable. For example, if you write in the command window: `A.b =1` and `A.c = 4`, then you will have a matrix A with 2 elements but Matlab still shows it as 1x1 matrix.

So, would you tell me what is this kind of declaration called? and in what way is this different than declaring a variable A which is 2x1?

Regards

Comment: See `help punct` for an interesting and concise description of the various punctuation operators used in MATLAB. This is the structure field access operator, as Robert P. notes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a struct.

```
A.b = 1;
A.c = 2;
```

is a 1x1 matrix, whereas the following would be a 2x1 matrix.

```
A(1).b = 1;
A(1).c = 2;
A(2).b = 1;
A(2).c = 2;
```

See the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you that clarifies its use.
Do you know if a data store memory in Simulink can be used to store struct variables?

Comment: Actually it could also be the call to the "set" function of a class.